# How to conditionally wrangle df from long to wide while modifying names in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a longitudinal df similar to the one below, where there is a row for each participant (`id`) at each visit number (`visit`). The same 3 variables are recorded at each visit. I want to have each participant as their own row,
but turn the values into wide format... and having the new variable name retaining the original variable name and appending the visit name to the end.
I'll have to repeat this many times so would like to avoid manually naming them after the fact. Ideas?

I have tried `dcast()`but can't seem to get my desired result. I think `pivot_wider()` may have a role here but can't figure it out.

```
# CURRENT:

# A tibble: 12 x 5
      id visit  var1  var2  var3
   <dbl> <txt> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     v1     1     1     1
 2     1     v2     1     2     1
 3     1     v3     2     2     1
 4     2     v1     1     1     1
 5     2     v2     1     2     1
 6     2     v3     2     2     1
 7     2     v4     2     2     2
 8     3     v1     1     1     1
 9     3     v2     1     2     1
10     3     v3     2     3     1
11     3     v4     2     3     2
12     3     v5     3     3     3




# DESIRED

# A tibble: 3 x 16
     id var1_v1 var1_v2 var1_v3 var1_v4 var1_v5 var2_v1 var2_v2 var2_v3 var2_v4 var2_v5 var3_v1 var3_v2 var3_v3 var3_v4 var3_v5
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1       1       1       3      NA      NA       1       2       2      NA      NA       1       1       1      NA      NA
2     2       1       1       2       2      NA       1       2       2       2      NA       1       1       2       1      NA
3     3       1       1       2       2       3       1       2       3       3       3       1       1       1       2       3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pivot_wider` :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = visit, values_from = starts_with('var'))

#     id var1_v1 var1_v2 var1_v3 var1_v4 var1_v5 var2_v1 var2_v2 var2_v3 var2_v4
#  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1     1       1       1       2      NA      NA       1       2       2      NA
#2     2       1       1       2       2      NA       1       2       2       2
#3     3       1       1       2       2       3       1       2       3       3
# … with 6 more variables: var2_v5 <int>, var3_v1 <int>, var3_v2 <int>,
#   var3_v3 <int>, var3_v4 <int>, var3_v5 <int>
```

In `data.table` using `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), id~visit, value.var = grep('^var', names(df), value = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could use:

```
reshape(df, timevar = "visit", dir="wide", sep="_")
```